# SearchView suggestions inside recyclerview (with API call onQueryTextChange)

Tags: java, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I would like to display suggestions in recyclerView instead of embedded UI of the searchView (like on picture below)

[image]

Suggestions are loaded from API call on each text query change of my searchView.
Then, each time I receipt new suggestions, I'm executing an AsyncTask which populate the UI suggestions using Cursor

```
class FetchSearchUserTermSuggestionsTask(var searchview: SearchView) : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, Cursor>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Cursor {
        val cursor =
            MatrixCursor(columnNamesArray)

        var list : List<UserSuggestionDto>? = null

        var call = RetrofitClient.userService.suggestionForTextSearch(0, 50, params[0]!!)

        val response  = call.execute()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            list = response.body()!!
        } else {
            //todo : throw exception
            Log.e(EventAddFragment.TAG, response.message())
            Log.e(EventAddFragment.TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
        }

        // parse your search terms into the MatrixCursor
        if(list != null) {
            for (index in list.indices) {
                val term = list[index].fullname
                val image = list[index].profilePic
                val id = list[index].id
                val row = arrayOf(index, id, image, term)
                cursor.addRow(row)
            }
        }
        return cursor
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Cursor) {
       searchview.suggestionsAdapter.changeCursor(result)
    }

    companion object {
        private val columnNamesArray = arrayOf(BaseColumns._ID,
            UserSuggestionDto.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ID,
            UserSuggestionDto.SUGGEST_COLUMN_IMAGE,
            UserSuggestionDto.SUGGEST_COLUMN_FULLNAME)
    }
}
```

Finally, I prefer to populate a recyclerView in a dedicated fragment for research of user.
Is There a specific way to do it ?

My fears are :

- RecyclerView is not designed to use Cursor and AsyncTask (Contrary to the searchView suggestions adapter)

So how to populate a recycler view from searchView on each text query change (by calling api each time) properly ?

Thanks in advance